# conditional property to access javascript object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have 2 object that has same data structure, how to make the property dynamic but use one liner

```
import user from '../user'
import user2 from '../user'

const myFunc = () => `${test === 1 ? user : user2}`.name
```

I can use temporary variable but would like to know one liner solution.

Comment: `${test === 1 ? user : user2}` - returns string. String type does not have `name` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is what you want.

`myFunc2` is similar to the one in your question whereas `myFunc` is what I would suggest wherein you can pass in the property that you want to access.

```js
const user = {name: "John", age: 34};
const user2 = {name: "Taylor", age: 21};
let test = 1;

const myFunc = (prop) => (test === 1 ? user : user2)[prop];
const myFunc2 = () => (test === 1 ? user : user2).name;

console.log(myFunc2())

test = 0;
console.log(myFunc("age"))
```